# Работа с IDD_FORMVIEW окном

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

1. Требуется ли для данного вида окна писать отдельную оконную функцию или можно(лучше) использовать основную WndProc!?
2. В какой момент нужно(лучше) создавать IDD_FORMVIEW окно CreateDialog`ом? при получении сообщения WM_CREATE ?
3. Как правильней задать размеры IDD_FORMVIEW окна, что бы вписать его в основное окно!?
4. Я вопросы задаю корректно? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не очень хорошая у меня память на константы VS, касательно ресурсов, но я так понимаю, речь идет о типе диалога в редакторе ресурсов. Если Вам необходимо управлять дочерними компонентами на этом диалоге через `WM_COMMAND` или `WM_NOTIFY`, то да - функцию диалога писать придется.
2. Да, на `WM_CREATE` будет достаточно.
3. Обычно в основном окне перехватывают `WM_SIZE` и устанавливают габариты FormView с приходящей шириной и высотой клиентской области основного окна.
4. Вполне. :) Главное - чтобы ответы им соответствовали. А то, вот бывает, назадает человек вопросов. Наполучает ответов. А поймет их как-то по-своему, быть может и неверно. И начинается канитель повторных вопросов, из пустого в порожнее. Вот здесь надо остановиться и понять, с какого места это недопонимание началось. Вернуться к нему и продолжить заполнять пробелы.